# No result on standard output when running expect

Tags: bash, command, expect

Whenever I try to run the script it doesn't show me any result on standard output.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect --
send [exec tail -f /var/opt/jboss/log/jbossall.log | grep -i "pattern"]
```

Please advise the reason.

Comment: Are you aware that with option -f your get only 10 last line and the consequently appearing once? So are you sure that after the invocation there is anything written to file with given pattern. Did you tested command without grepping, just to see if given pattern appears?

Comment: yes, to answer your query :the logfile (jbossall.log) JBoss logs from the asf servers always written at every millisecond for the transactions on the system.

Comment: Also, yes, the file is always written with the given pattern. EVen i tested the command without and some more commands such as :: #!/usr/bin/expect --
send [exec date]
send [exec tail -F /var/opt/jboss/log/jbossall.log]

Comment: the output shows date on standard output but nothing from jbossall.log file :-(

Comment: Just to add...I'm running this script on my LINUX system in $HOME as ./expect_learn_1.sh

Comment: Just to add...I'm running this script on my LINUX system in $HOME as ./expect_learn_1.sh.
#!/usr/bin/expect -- 
send [exec date] send [exec tail -F /var/opt/jboss/log/jbossall.log]].
Result as ::       
Thu Sep 23 10:47:52 IST 2010                                 
Then pressed ctrl+c, the standard output shows
unable to alloc 226180663 bytes
Aborted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `exec` command never completes because you're using `tail -f`.  From the info page for tail: "**Loop forever** trying to read more characters at the end of the file".  Since `exec` does not complete, `send` is never invoked.

You probably need to do something like this:

```
spawn whatever
set whatever_id $spawn_id

spawn sh -c {tail -f /var/opt/jboss/log/jbossall.log | grep -i "pattern"}
set tail_id $spawn_id

while {1} {
    expect -i $tail_id "(.*)\n"
    send -i $whatever_id $expect_out(1,string)
}
```

Comment: I offer two implementation details that Glenn fully understands, but that might be of value to user451404 or other readers:  1.  "... while 1 ..." in Expect source is often more idiomatically expressed with exp_continue; and, depending on the nature of "whatever" at the top, it might be preferable to write this script in terms of Expect-free standard line-oriented Tcl.